# How to enable laravel5.3 auth to register users after login?

Tags: laravel, authentication

i want to  user after login with own credentials,be able to register new users.
i using laravel5.3 and built-in Authentication  system.
how to change Authentication system for this feature?
thanks

Comment: This is not an "ask and you shall receive" kind of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change authentication system for that. You can allow some user to create a new user manually:

```
public function createNewUser(Request $request)
{
    if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        $request->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user = User::create($request->all());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to create another user just copy your register form to a place inside a view a logged in user can view.

Set the action of the form to a route i.e. http://yoursite/newuser for example.

Call a function in your controller 
Get the input ->
here I get the password from the input in order to encrypt it and then putting it back to the input

```
     public function createuser(Request $request)
    {
        $transf_password = Input::get('password');
        $input = Input::except('password');
        $transf_password = bcrypt($transf_password);

        $input += array('password' => $transf_password);
        User::create($input);
        return back();
}
```

You are done.